# Почему не запускается Umbrello (UML редактор) после установки?

Tags: windows

Я использую Windows 11.

После установки Umbrello я пытаюсь запустить программу, но после нажатия на ярлык ничего не происходит.

Я пробовал переустановить, но это не помогло. Java установлен.

На другом устройстве с той же ОС все работает нормально.

Загружено с официального сайта: https://download.kde.org/stable/umbrello/latest/win64/

Пожалуйста, подскажите мне решение этой проблемы.

Ссылка на видео на Google диске: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JbgqxaPkqLlswqxzuiHjhhHMDT-X-_R5/view?usp=sharing

Если вы не знаете решения этой проблемы или у вас все работает нормально, не удаляйте этот вопрос.